# Cocos2d-x game crashes on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, cocos2d-x

Hi my app is able to run on a real device but I'm having trouble running it on the android emulator. It crashes on startup. I have tried using x86 architecture along with ARM architecture and am getting the same results. I have Use Host Gpu checked and am running Android 4.4.2. Here is my logcat output:

```
03-02 21:46:21.915: W/dalvikvm(1264): JNI WARNING: illegal class name 'org.cocos2dx.hellocpp/HelloCpp' (FindClass)
03-02 21:46:21.915: W/dalvikvm(1264):              (should be formed like 'dalvik/system/DexFile')
03-02 21:46:21.915: W/dalvikvm(1264):              or '[Ldalvik/system/DexFile;' or '[[B')
03-02 21:46:21.915: I/dalvikvm(1264): "GLThread 90" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
03-02 21:46:21.925: I/dalvikvm(1264):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb1d43ba0 self=0xb7cbe6b8
03-02 21:46:21.925: I/dalvikvm(1264):   | sysTid=1277 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1211372784
03-02 21:46:21.925: I/dalvikvm(1264):   | state=R schedstat=( 1580000000 2400000000 209 ) utm=101 stm=57 core=0
03-02 21:46:21.995: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #00  pc 0000132e  /system/lib/libcorkscrew.so (unwind_backtrace_thread+29)
03-02 21:46:21.995: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #01  pc 000603ea  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget const*, int)+33)
03-02 21:46:21.995: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #02  pc 000543e4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*, Thread*, bool)+395)
03-02 21:46:21.995: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #03  pc 00054452  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+25)
03-02 21:46:21.995: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #04  pc 0003871c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-02 21:46:21.995: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #05  pc 000416c8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-02 21:46:21.995: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #06  pc 0033f1ec  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (_JNIEnv::FindClass(char const*)+40)
03-02 21:46:21.995: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #07  pc 0033f4fc  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp-1/libcocos2dcpp.so
03-02 21:46:21.995: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #08  pc 0033f5b4  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp-1/libcocos2dcpp.so
03-02 21:46:21.995: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #09  pc 0033f95c  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(cocos2d::JniMethodInfo_&, char const*, char const*, char const*)+44)
03-02 21:46:21.995: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #10  pc 001a120c  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (setVisibleAdmobJNI+60)
03-02 21:46:21.995: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #11  pc 001a2044  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (MainMenu::showAdmob()+20)
03-02 21:46:21.995: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #12  pc 001a1f18  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (MainMenu::init()+2304)
03-02 21:46:21.995: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #13  pc 001a1544  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (MainMenu::create()+96)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #14  pc 001a15dc  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (MainMenu::scene()+24)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #15  pc 0019c3f8  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()+96)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #16  pc 00339104  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::CCApplication::run()+40)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #17  pc 0019c0f4  /data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeInit+184)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #18  pc 0001dbcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #19  pc 0004defe  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+393)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #20  pc 0003873c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCheckCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+7)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #21  pc 0004f8ea  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmResolveNativeMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+181)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #22  pc 00026fe0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #23  pc 0002df34  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #24  pc 0002b5cc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #25  pc 00060318  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+335)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #26  pc 0006033c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+19)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #27  pc 0005502a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #28  pc 0000d060  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   #29  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeInit(Native Method)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(Cocos2dxRenderer.java:72)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1501)
03-02 21:46:22.005: I/dalvikvm(1264):   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
03-02 21:46:22.005: E/dalvikvm(1264): VM aborting
03-02 21:46:22.015: A/libc(1264): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000004f0 (code=-6), thread 1277 (Thread-90)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing in `findClass` Java JNI code related to AdMob. Make sure you have added jar file in your `Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries` and if it's already added then make sure it must be checked in your `Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export`

Comment: it works on real device though? and im using the new google play services abmob

Comment: Did you noticed `JNI WARNING: illegal class name 'org.cocos2dx.hellocpp/HelloCpp' (FindClass)` . Class name must be like `org/cocos2dx/YourActivity`

Comment: You are calling Java method using JNI, therefore you must provide fully qualified java class name in your `setVisibleAdmobJNI` function